# Postgresql regex_replace comma, single and double quotes in a single

Tags: sql, postgresql, replace, regexp-replace

I have a string which consists of  double quotes, single quotes and commas. I would like to replace all the occurrences of them using regex_replace.

Tried

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(translate (links, '"',''), '['''''',]'        , '')
```

It replaces the first occurrence of comma not the second one.

```
'https://google.com/khjdbgksdngksd#/","https://google.com/khjdbgksdngksd#/","'
```

Comment: Replace with what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you mixing TRANSLATE and REGEXP_REPLACE?  Just pick one and use it, as either one can do all that you want.

If you want REGEXP_REPLACE to replace **all** instances, you have to give it a fourth argument (the flag argument) of 'g' for 'global', otherwise it stops after the first match and substitution.

Also, to preserve sanity I would use dollar-quoting when the thing being quoted has single quote marks (which yours has in considerable excess).

Using TRANSLATE is probably a better tool for the job, but your title was specifically about REGEXP_REPLACE, so:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(links, $$[',"]$$, '', 'g');
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use `replace()`?

```
select replace(replace(replace(links, '"', ''), '''', ''), ',', '')
```

Or more simply, use `translate()`:

```
select translate(links, '"'',', '')
```